# Trying to bring a JLabel above Paint

Tags: java, swing, paint, jlabel, imageicon

Been trying to create a program which basically has a background (Which is painted using Paint() ) and then putting a Label with an Image in above that.

Keep getting the JLabel underneath the Paint...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JPanel menuBar = new JPanel();
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Press Me");
    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    private ImageIcon image1;
    private static JLabel label1;

    public GUI() {
        super("Add a profile");

        setLayout(null);

        try {
            image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                    "Images/location.PNG"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Image not found!");
        }
        label1 = new JLabel(image1);
        label1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(262, 94), label1.getPreferredSize()));
        label1.setLocation(1, 1);
        label1.setSize(114, 105);
        add(label1);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Menu Bar
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(60, 93, 190, 373);
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(61, 94, 189, 372);

        // Background box
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRect(281, 106, 560, 360);
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2d.fillRect(282, 107, 559, 359);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.setSize(900, 550);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setResizable(false);
        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
```

### }

Sadly can't get it to work, thanks a bunch anyway
Oh i didn't see the images you did! Sorry! i'll have a look through now

Really appreciate it all!

Comment: Show us the code.  `paint` is responsible for painting the child components as well as the background, in the case of Swing components this calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  The correct way to update the background of a component is via the `paintComponent` method.  You might like to have a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of you're code, you're trying to use paint to do the work of other containers.  I'd suggest, don't.

Don't override the `paint` method of top level containers like `JFrame`, these methods do to much important work for you to messy about it with and frames have a number of components already laid out on top of them normally rendering any of your work obsolete.

Instead, create your self a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and use it's `paintComponent` method instead THEN add this to the frame.

In you're case, you can get away with changing the background and border of the component and it will achieve the same result.

**UPDATED**

[image]

With just some basic layouts and a couple of components, I was able to produce this...

```
public class BadPaint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadPaint();
    }

    public BadPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new MenuPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

            BackgroundPane left = new BackgroundPane();
            left.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" Menu ");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            left.add(label);
            add(left, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(40, 10, 40, 10);
            BackgroundPane right = new BackgroundPane();
            right.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel(" Content ");
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            right.add(label);
            add(right, gbc);

        }

    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        public BackgroundPane() {
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        }

    }

}
```

I'd suggest you would benefit from having a read through

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)